# How do I calculate the angle between two sides of a polygon?

Tags: trigonometry, polygons

So I got a polygon and I have all of the points. What  I need, is to find all internal angles of this irregular polygon. How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Please give us a more exact description of the definition of your polygon

Comment: What do you know: Law of Cosines?  Dot product?

Comment: Very unclear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all the edge positions of the polygon, then you should definitely compute the angles by the dot product between the two edges vectors that generate this angle. More precisely, if you have three points $A=(x_a,y_a)$, $B=(x_b,y_b)$ and $C=(x_c,y_c)$, and you need to compute the angle $\widehat{ABC}$, then you generate the vectors $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ and you can compute : 
$$
\theta = \arccos ( \frac{\vec{BA} . \vec{BC}}{\|\vec{BA}\|\|\vec{BC}\|}) 
$$